# Is on-the-fly compiling in WinRt possible?

Tags: c#, windows-8, compilation, windows-runtime, on-the-fly

For a project I need to compile code on-the-fly in a WinRt-application. Almost nothing I can find on that subject. I've seen the CodeDom-namespace has sadly enough only one class, which I fear means a no to the question.

So, is it still possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible.  WinRT apps are sandboxed and deliberately locked-down to enhance their security.